# Typescript How Add a Function as A Porpety to an Object

Tags: javascript, typescript, function, object

I am trying to set up a lookup to obtain functions for decoding.

Information is stored in an array of objects of the form:

```
{ SourceType: string; DestType: string, Importer:Function }[]
```

What I would like to do is import a function

```
import {fred} from "ethel"
```

and then fill an array of objects the object with:

```
{SourceType:"Input", DestType: "Output", Importer:fred}
```

However, when I do this, Importer is `undefined`.

I can write a wrapper function, but that seems to be dodging the issues.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Doesn't that mean `fred` is undefined?

Comment: if you used a default export, try `import fred from "ethel"`, or if it is your own local file module `import {fred} from "./ethel"`.

Comment: I should have typed 

import {fred} from "./ethel"

and fred is defined and exported in the imported module